# Toast Is not showing in Login Flow when giving call to HTTP request

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app's login page 
I have email & password fields and a sign in button.

The button first gets the username and password, then creates a toast, 
and then calls a separate kotlin file to make a http request with the login details.

The weird thing is:
If the credentials are incorrect the toast appears, 
but when the credentials are correct and the server responds with data the toast never shows.

I would understand however the order of execution should be that the toast is displayed **before** the http call is ever made.

```
btn_signin.setOnClickListener(){
    val username = et_username.text.toString().trim()
    val password = et_password.text.toString().trim()
    var toast_text = "Signing you in..."
    Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val resp = Punchcard().Login(username = username, password = password)
}
```

Have tried changing the length to short with no difference.
Surely this should display regardless of the following code?

EDIT:

This is in file LoginActivity.kt, I have edited the above code a little.

Another separate file (Punchcard.kt) handles the call to an API on a server, which all works fine and is not causing any issues. It should in theory have absolutely nothing to do with the Toast, it's just odd that the processing in a separate file seems to be taking away from the creation of the Toast. Am I crazy for thinking they should be unrelated and Android's display flow should be line by line?

EDIT2:

This is the Punchcard.kt Login function, makes an okhttp3 call to an API and returns the response as a string. Before it's mentioned I know I shouldn't be passing the password string, this is a flaw in the API I am using but will be updated in future. Also as mentioned above this should not have any effect as the toast is called **before** the login function.

```
fun Login(username : String, password : String): String {
    val url: String = "http://192.168.8.200:3001/api/auth/signin"
    val json = JSONObject()
    json.put("usernameOrEmail", username)
    json.put("password", password)
    val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString())
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build()
    val policy : StrictMode.ThreadPolicy  = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
    try {
        var response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        return response.body()?.string() ?: "error"
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        println(e)
    }
    return "error"
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code where you are checking the credentials

Comment: Use `ProgressDialog` to show your message before Login, because Login call may take time to login.

Comment: `ProgressDialog` is deprecated. Don't use Dialogs for loading indicators @PrachiSingh

Comment: @Zun If ProgressDialog is deprecated so what is the alternative for ProgressDialog?

Comment: @PrachiSingh the alternate is either to use alert dialog or progress bar,

Comment: @Umair these are not alternatives..ProgressBar in AlertDialog is just Jugaad.. :)

Comment: The whole idea of creating a blocking dialog is deprecated, not just the ProgressDialog class. Google no longer recommends using dialogs. https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html

Comment: Can we see the PunchCard.kt file? Also, you say the toast is displayed if the credentials are "incorrect". Who determines that the credentials are incorrect? I hope you are still making the server call in this case too.

Comment: @RahulShukla code added in edit2. Yes the server is still called, that's how we know the details are incorrect, login details are validated by the API on the server.

Comment: 1. Remove thread policy. 2. Call this function in a separate thread 3. Modify your call to handle asynchronous Login() call and it's result. 4.Check if it works.

Comment: @Zun If ProgressDialog is deprecated then why it doesn't have strike-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved desired result by moving to using async call running on background thread.
Still doesn't explain why the toast doesn't show before the call is made, however in my project this is no longer an issue. It seems that Rahul suggested what I had already done to solve this in comments so good karma to him.
If anyone has an actual explanation for why this happens I'd still be interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Toast.makeText(applicationContext,toast_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

This is working. Use this once.

Answer (score 0):

1) Suppose your Toast is in Activity and in subclass than use below code:

`Toast.makeText(this, "Hi there! This is a Toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

or

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

2) In Fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(activity, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

3) Using method:

```
fun Activity.toast(message: CharSequence, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
  Toast.makeText(this, message, duration).show()
}

class MainActivity : Activity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        toast("Hello, Kotlin!")
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear the toast DOES display if my credentials are incorrect, it's just when they are correct and the separate 'helper' file takes a while to respond on the line AFTER the toast create the toast does not appear. IMHO The toast should appear regardless of what happens with the call on the following line as it should be processed line by line.